# Ordering objects in java *without* using values

Tags: java, libraries, partial-ordering

I want to create a class of objects to compare to each other, without using values to compare them with. Is there a library in Java which is able to provide this functionality for me? In terms of ordering, the most frequently mentioned library is Comparator, but all the examples I have seen so far use some kinds of value from the objects in order to perform this ordering with.

For example, I want to be able to say that within a class of objects that:

Object A is more important than Object B. 
Object B is more important than Object C.

Therefore, I want the library to be able to perform some kind of analysis, and to be able to order the items according to these values, and say to me, that the order of the values above are A, B, C, in that order.

Is there a library which is able to do this in Java?

Comment: How you determine that Objact A is more important than Object B? Give the example.

Comment: I think you totally can do it using..... Comparator

Comment: @aviad, without values... how? only examples i have seen use values...

Comment: "Importance" is a value. Perhaps it is static on the Class level rather than on the instance but it is still a value.

Comment: If you're not using a value of the object (As in a property value that you define), perhaps the objects size (in bytes) or its hash value?

Comment: You still haven't explained how you decide which is more important, given two objects.

Comment: @sotirios the comparison should be something the library allows you to state. Object A > Object B. obviously without this, the comparison is impossible. i do not need to compare values, I want to create a graph of comparisons based on importance.

Comment: So like `thiz(someObject).isBiggerThan(otherObject)` and you build up a chain?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
enum Importance {

    High,
    Medium,
    Low;
}

class Thing implements Comparable<Thing> {

    private Importance importance = Importance.Medium;

    public Importance getImportance() {
        return importance;
    }

    public void setImportance(Importance importance) {
        this.importance = importance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Thing o) {
        return importance.compareTo(o.importance);
    }

}
```

Alternatively - if you want to control the relativity of each object then record that in a Map. You will need to be careful to tightly control the map to ensure there are no cycles - if there is then your sorting will become unstable.

```
static Map<Thing, Set<Thing>> moreImportant = new HashMap<>();

class Thing implements Comparable<Thing> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Thing o) {
        Set<Thing> more = moreImportant.get(this);
        return more == null ? 0 : more.contains(o) ? 1 : -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: if i have 100 objects, which i want to compare, i can't assign each of them a value of these three (assuming i want to give them all a comparison to another object). i want to be able to say for each object, an object that it is more important than.

Comment: @karamurat - See additional option.